# My c program is not giving proper result

Tags: c

The following code is not working properly.
scanf and printf statements in the ques2() function are not working in execution. please help me with it.

```
void main()
{
   printf("\t\t\t\t\tKBC");
   ques1();
}

void ques1()
{
   char c; 
   printf("\nQ1 WHAT IS THE CAPITAL OF INDIA?");
   printf("\na. Delhi \tb. Kolkata");
   printf("\nc. Rome \td. China\n");
   scanf("%c",&c);
   if(c=='a')
   {
      ques2();
   }
   else printf("wrong answer");
}

ques2()
{
   printf("ques2");
   char d;
   scanf("%c",&d);
   printf("%c",d);
   ques3();
}

ques3()
{
   printf("ques3");
   char d;
   scanf("%c",&d);
   printf("%c",d);
}
```

Comment: You must declare both `ques2()` and `ques3()` as void if they do not return anything.

Comment: Very similar to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28007982/841108) to a quite similar question

Comment: BTW, `main` should not be declared `void` but `int main(int argc, char**argv)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use:

```
scanf("%c",&c);
```

the newline character is still left in the input stream after the character is read. Next time such a statement is used, the newline character is read into `c`. If you want to skip leading whitespaces, replace the format in those to `" %c"`.

```
scanf(" %c",&c);
```

Make that change in `ques1`, `ques2`, and `ques3`.

**Update, in response to OP's comment**

When you use

```
scanf("%c",&c);
```

If your type `a` followed by <kbd>Enter</kbd>, then the first `scanf` stores `'a'` in `c`. The second `scanf` stores a `'\n'` in `c`.

When you use

```
scanf(" %c",&c);
```

all leading whitespace characters are skipped. Hence, the `'\n'` from the input stream is not read into `c`.

Comment: Your answer helped me getting the right output but I am not able to get the explanation. @R Sahu

Answer (score 0):

I got another answer to the question. There is another method of clearing memory of the buffer i.e fflush(stdin) before scanf statement

this function clears anything that is in the buffer and then allow us to use scanf simply.