# Having code issue in C

Tags: c, arrays, class, structure

Can anyone please tell me what is the problem with this code?

There is no issue in the compilation of this code but after compilation when I enter the data of Array of Objects of structure, the data is not entered after one loop.

```
#include<stdio.h>
struct process{
    char name;
    int arv;
    int burst;
}p[10];
int sort(struct process p[],int n){
    int i,j;
struct process t;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        for(j=0;j<n-1-i;j++){
            if(p[j].arv>p[j+1].arv){
                p[j]=t;
                p[j]=p[j+1];
                p[j+1]=t;
            }
        }
    }
return 0;
}
int main(){
    int i,n;
    printf("Enter Number Of Processes");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        scanf("%c",&p[i].name);
        scanf("%d",&p[i].arv);
        scanf("%d",&p[i].burst);
    }
    sort(p,n);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        printf("%c",p[i].name);
        printf("%d",p[i].arv);
        printf("%d",p[i].burst);
    }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: It should be `fflush(stdout);` or `fflush(NULL);` and you should add it at the end of each `for` loop body.

Comment: @nIcEcOw One does not simply `fflush(stdin)`.

Comment: `fflush(stdin)` causes undefined behaviour, don't try that

Comment: BTW, you should compile with all warnings & debug info (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`) and you should **use the debugger** (`gdb`)

Comment: try adding some prints after the first scanf and for the data entered. see where it went wrong

Comment: @all : Apologizing, for my mistake. But I am not good in some aspects of C. So will try to learn, from others for some more time, before even commenting now :-)

Comment: Checkout [my answer to another SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28007871/434551). It think your problem is the same as the problem in the other question.

Comment: @vaibhav can you describe the problem you are actually having

Comment: Idea: how about assigning something to `t` in your swap rather than using it as the rhs of two assignments. The first should be `t = p[j];`, you have `p[j] = t;`

Answer (score 3):

Read documentation of [scanf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html) and of [fflush(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fflush.3.html)

Always test the result of `scanf`

```
printf("Enter Number Of Processes");
fflush(NULL);
if (scanf("%d",&n)<1) 
 { perror("scanf nb process"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); ; }
```

<sup>(do likewise for your other calls to `scanf` ...)</sup>

and at least call `fflush` at end of each `for`  loop, e.g.

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++){
    printf("%c",p[i].name);
    printf("%d",p[i].arv);
    printf("%d",p[i].burst);
    fflush(NULL);
}
```

since [stdio(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/stdio.3.html) is *buffered*. BTW, you'll be surprised by the output. You generally should end each (or at least most) `printf` format string with `\n`

BTW, you should compile with all warnings & debug info (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`) and you should use the debugger (`gdb`)

Comment: You are right. IIRC on Linux `scanf` is calling `fflush` in some cases.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, you are facing problem with `scanf()`. But do not use `fflush()` as some of above answers suggest to use `fflush(NULL)` before `scanf()`. `fflush()` on input streams as `stdin` has undefined behaviour, [Read Here fflush()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fflush.3.html)

Instead use following to clear the `stdin` before every scanf.

`while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n')
    ;`

It clears the newline character pressed after last input, which is not absorbed by `scanf()`

also check the return of `scanf()`, thats a good habit always.